# My div becomes mysteriously wrapped into my form. How do I fix?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

For some reason my div tag becomes wrapped into my form tag on this page. All I can think of is that the asp:literal is the culprit but I can't think of why it would be? In my code behind file I am inserting a table, but why it would make my footer div become wrapped up into it is beyond me. There's an img below showing what Google Chrome's developer output showed me and I'm just baffled as to WHY it would put the footer div there?

I used the normal footer and main tags, but still had the same result. I tried re-doing my div hierarchy to no avail. Right now my footer in the css has a position of absolute which is tied to a container div in an attempt to make it stick to the bottom and this did actually help keep it at the bottom, but as you can see in the image it is STILL not where it is supposed to be and when rendered it is shifted to the right because of my styling on the div that contains the form. Ugh!

Now I have three other pages in the website that contain forms and this is not a problem which is why I am pretty sure it is something with the creation of the table in my code behind file.

This is part of the .aspx file

```
<div id="body">
    <div class="intro">
        <div class="center">
             <h2>Current Schedule</h2>
             <form id="scheduleForm" runat="server">
                 <asp:Literal ID="schedule" runat="server" />
             </form>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>2010 © Copyright Central Valley Utilities. All rights reserved. Read Legal policy and Privacy policy.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code behind file which creates a table to the asp:Literal tag "schedule".

```
if (scheduleRecords.Read())
{
schedule.Text += "<table width='100%' border='1'>";
schedule.Text += "<tr><th>Class</th><th>Days</th><th>Time</th>";
do
{
  schedule.Text += "<tr>";
  schedule.Text += "<td>" + scheduleRecords["class"] + "</td>";
  schedule.Text += "<td>" + scheduleRecords["days"] + "</td>";
  schedule.Text += "<td>" + scheduleRecords["time"] + "</td>";
  schedule.Text += "</tr>";
 } while (scheduleRecords.Read());
 schedule.Text += "</tr>";
```

JPG of Google Chrome's output showing the footer above the form

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many `</div>` tags, so the `<div id='body'>` tag is close before the footer.

```
<div id="body">
    <div class="intro">
        <div class="center">
            <h2>Current Schedule</h2>
            <form id="scheduleForm" runat="server">
                <asp:Literal ID="schedule" runat="server" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <-- Here
<div id="footer">
    <p>2010 © Copyright Central Valley Utilities. All rights reserved. Read Legal policy and Privacy policy.</p>
</div>
</div> <-- Or Here
```

Remove one of those two divs (probably the second one).

Also, the code for your literal is not creating a closing table tag.

```
if (scheduleRecords.Read())
{
    schedule.Text += "<table width='100%' border='1'>";
    schedule.Text += "<tr><th>Class</th><th>Days</th><th>Time</th></tr>"; <-- move </tr> to here
    do
    {
        schedule.Text += "<tr>";
        schedule.Text += "<td>" + scheduleRecords["class"] + "</td>";
        schedule.Text += "<td>" + scheduleRecords["days"] + "</td>";
        schedule.Text += "<td>" + scheduleRecords["time"] + "</td>";
        schedule.Text += "</tr>";
     } while (scheduleRecords.Read());

     schedule.Text += "</table>"; <-- Here
}
```

Comment: Look at `schedule.Text += "</tr>";` before `...</table>` as well. It should be just before `do`.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev good catch, it should be at the end of the header row just before the `do`.

Comment: Yes it was the closing tag for the table that I missed in my code behind file. Thank you for catching that! I can't believe I missed something as simple as that.